# How to publish Directus on free hosting?

Tags: content-management-system, headless, directus

Is it possible to host/deploy Directus (Headless CMS) on some free hosting like GitHub?

Now I have Directus on my localhost, I installed it just with
npm init directus-project api // create directus HEADLES CMS in API folder

then I have an access to it via http://localhost:8055/

Answer (score 1):

It can really depend. GitHub will be a definite no as a 'free hosting provider' for any node apps, as GitHub Pages will only host static pages (AFAIK).

There aren't many free hosting providers that will support NodeJS applications, you might be able to find one host out there somewhere but it may take some work searching as all free providers have their own restrictions and there's no guarantee you'll have the freedom to build what you need.

I would highly recommend a Digital Ocean $5 Droplet, it's very cheap, and great at hosting Directus.

Comment: What do you think about Heroku?

Comment: I've not tried Heroku, personally, I just use a Digital Ocean due to the full SSH Access. I've always found that free tiers of hosting have silly limitations, one subdomain, or two ports forwarded or something. If it's free though, no harm in giving it a go yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use free/hobby plan of [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

Directus also provides [one-click install](https://github.com/directus/directus#-one-click-deployments) on many platforms including heroku. Check out their GitHub page and read [docs](https://docs.directus.io/) to learn more.